WebRTC: audio/video from remote peer is received exactly once yes and once no on Firefox
I'm working on a WebRTC project that requires moderated webinar-type rooms.
On the server side it is based on Pion for SFU,
and on the browser side on a proprietary javascript client.
After several days of debugging,
I have still not been able to resolve the following behavior which only occurs on Firefox:
the broadcast to the participants works exactly once every other time.
Below I have included the room join SDPs for two peers A and B,
and those between peer A and the SFU, when changing the broadcast state of peer B.
This is a summary of what I can observe in peer A side
each time I enable the broadcast of the peer B.
Similar behaviors/info when the broadcast fails or succeeds:

both peers are on Firefox
the SDPs generated by the SFU are similar, except for the mid identifiers,
the audio/video tracks are always there
negotiations never fail
ontrack events are fired for both tracks on the javascript side
codecs used are OPUS/VP8 for both peers
the m-lines and related transceivers seem to change direction correctly
the videoElement.srcObject is correctly set to a MediaStream object, with both audio and video MediaStreamTracks having muted=false, enable=true, readyState=live
there are no pending streams in either case in the javascript client,
an applicative-level stream is pending when:

ontrack is not fired, for all the required tracks
all the applicative-level signaling events to initialize the new view is not received


firefox about:webrtc shows:

ICE state succeeded selecting a trickled candidate that is nominated and selected:
local: 192.168.1.3:58968/udp(host) [non-proxied]
remote: 192.168.1.3:41440/udp(host)



Different behaviors/info when the broadcast fail:

the audio/video tracks have reversed order (video first) in the SDP sent by the SFU to peer A
onunmute event is triggered only for video track, but the view is blank
when muting video track for peer B while broadcasting is enabled,
onunmute event for the audio track is triggered on peer A,
and the audio track becomes audible
if the video track is keep muted for peer B while broadcasting
is enabled/disabled, the peer A can always ear peer B
I see only an inbound-rtp audio track when it doesn't works,
and inbound-rtp audio+video tracks when it works

Update 1
Inbound audio track for the non-working case, note the high packet loss:
Decoder: 111 audio/opus2 channels 48000 maxplaybackrate=48000;stereo=1;useinbandfec=1
Local: 15:39:28 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) inbound-rtpReceived 21,854 packets (1728.69 Kb , 8.0 KBps)Lost -10,927 packetsJitter 0.002
Update 2
Enabling/disabling broadcast for peer B I can also observe this on webrtc internals:

after the join there are only 2 outbound tracks, as expected
broadcast activation: there are 2 inbound and 2 outbound tracks, as expected
broadcast deactivation: 1 inbound video track (leaked?) and 2 outbound tracks (peer B audio/video)
broadcast activation: 1 inbound audio track with different SSRC and 2 outbound tracks (peer B audio/video)
broadcast deactivation: only 2 outbound tracks (audio/video), as expected

Note: although webrtc internals gives different results, on the javascript side the "similar behaviors/info" described above are always consistent (always both tracks, states, etc.).
To reply to comments below:

I don't think it's an HDMI driver problem. I conducted the tests on Firefox (doesn't work) and Chrome (works) in the same PC and local development environment, using the same devices, or fake devices to work cross-browser, without changes in the results. By muting the audio, the video is not displayed, only the opposite works.


...snip....
Due to body limitation of 30k characters I have excluded SDPs exchange between peers and SFU to join the room.
You can find full info here.
...snip....
Peers A and B are succesfully connected to the SFU,
and neither of them sees the other as required.

From here only peer A renegotiate with the SFU.
Now peer B broadcasting is enabled to the participants (in that case the only peer A)
Remote SDP (offer from SFU)
v=0
o=- 6404238063867404676 1713866681 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
s=-
t=0 0
a=fingerprint:sha-256 47:6A:71:15:C0:01:A4:3E:B6:AC:C6:8B:E2:84:B1:C0:1D:49:6F:F1:14:0C:1F:C4:BD:B2:30:56:10:BB:9D:36
a=group:BUNDLE 0 1 2
m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 0 8 9
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:0
a=ice-ufrag:WRtsEOiaoItPEqup
a=ice-pwd:eadmhjMMzpurJPeaIqdGCwUyihOpRLzv
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=ssrc:556646705 cname:{ccedd829-80b6-4d6e-95d5-5ea497e9a4fd}
a=ssrc:556646705 msid:{ccedd829-80b6-4d6e-95d5-5ea497e9a4fd} 6e65e23b-ca79-49c9-8fa2-1c8edada26e8
a=ssrc:556646705 mslabel:{ccedd829-80b6-4d6e-95d5-5ea497e9a4fd}
a=ssrc:556646705 label:6e65e23b-ca79-49c9-8fa2-1c8edada26e8
a=msid:{ccedd829-80b6-4d6e-95d5-5ea497e9a4fd} 6e65e23b-ca79-49c9-8fa2-1c8edada26e8
a=sendrecv
a=candidate:foundation 1 udp 2130706431 192.168.1.3 34668 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 2 udp 2130706431 192.168.1.3 34668 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 1 udp 2130706431 192.168.122.1 53777 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 2 udp 2130706431 192.168.122.1 53777 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 1 udp 2130706431 172.17.0.1 49086 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 2 udp 2130706431 172.17.0.1 49086 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 1 udp 16777215 2.32.201.189 51726 typ relay raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 54578 generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 2 udp 16777215 2.32.201.189 51726 typ relay raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 54578 generation 0
a=end-of-candidates
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 98 102
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:1
a=ice-ufrag:WRtsEOiaoItPEqup
a=ice-pwd:eadmhjMMzpurJPeaIqdGCwUyihOpRLzv
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000
a=rtpmap:102 H264/90000
a=fmtp:102 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42001f
a=ssrc:2184094840 cname:{ccedd829-80b6-4d6e-95d5-5ea497e9a4fd}
a=ssrc:2184094840 msid:{ccedd829-80b6-4d6e-95d5-5ea497e9a4fd} ed97af1a-2ed6-4f13-9ca5-7a70008c7d9a
a=ssrc:2184094840 mslabel:{ccedd829-80b6-4d6e-95d5-5ea497e9a4fd}
a=ssrc:2184094840 label:ed97af1a-2ed6-4f13-9ca5-7a70008c7d9a
a=msid:{ccedd829-80b6-4d6e-95d5-5ea497e9a4fd} ed97af1a-2ed6-4f13-9ca5-7a70008c7d9a
a=sendrecv
a=candidate:foundation 1 udp 2130706431 192.168.1.3 34668 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 2 udp 2130706431 192.168.1.3 34668 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 1 udp 2130706431 192.168.122.1 53777 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 2 udp 2130706431 192.168.122.1 53777 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 1 udp 2130706431 172.17.0.1 49086 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 2 udp 2130706431 172.17.0.1 49086 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 1 udp 16777215 2.32.201.189 51726 typ relay raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 54578 generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 2 udp 16777215 2.32.201.189 51726 typ relay raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 54578 generation 0
a=end-of-candidates
m=application 9 DTLS/SCTP 5000
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:2
a=sendrecv
a=sctpmap:5000 webrtc-datachannel 1024
a=ice-ufrag:WRtsEOiaoItPEqup
a=ice-pwd:eadmhjMMzpurJPeaIqdGCwUyihOpRLzv
a=candidate:foundation 1 udp 2130706431 192.168.1.3 34668 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 2 udp 2130706431 192.168.1.3 34668 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 1 udp 2130706431 192.168.122.1 53777 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 2 udp 2130706431 192.168.122.1 53777 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 1 udp 2130706431 172.17.0.1 49086 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 2 udp 2130706431 172.17.0.1 49086 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 1 udp 16777215 2.32.201.189 51726 typ relay raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 54578 generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 2 udp 16777215 2.32.201.189 51726 typ relay raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 54578 generation 0
a=end-of-candidates

Local SDP (answer from Firefox)
v=0
o=mozilla...THIS_IS_SDPARTA-99.0 957846499555280282 2 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
s=-
t=0 0
a=fingerprint:sha-256 F1:90:80:57:6B:21:4B:3B:46:39:BE:EC:DD:DA:8B:EB:0B:41:CA:39:42:87:F6:71:CC:DD:E9:86:4D:3D:F4:00
a=group:BUNDLE 0 1 2
a=ice-options:trickle
a=msid-semantic:WMS *
m=audio 35036 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 0 8 9
c=IN IP4 2.32.201.189
a=candidate:0 1 UDP 2122252543 192.168.1.3 45832 typ host
a=candidate:3 1 UDP 2122187007 192.168.122.1 57330 typ host
a=candidate:6 1 UDP 2122121471 172.17.0.1 57309 typ host
a=candidate:9 1 TCP 2105524479 192.168.1.3 9 typ host tcptype active
a=candidate:11 1 TCP 2105458943 192.168.122.1 9 typ host tcptype active
a=candidate:13 1 TCP 2105393407 172.17.0.1 9 typ host tcptype active
a=candidate:10 1 UDP 8331263 2.32.201.189 35036 typ relay raddr 2.32.201.189 rport 35036
a=candidate:12 1 UDP 8265727 2.32.201.189 50962 typ relay raddr 2.32.201.189 rport 50962
a=candidate:14 1 UDP 8200191 2.32.201.189 50650 typ relay raddr 2.32.201.189 rport 50650
a=sendrecv
a=end-of-candidates
a=fmtp:111 maxplaybackrate=48000;stereo=1;useinbandfec=1
a=ice-pwd:ad33262c89431a763c05ff11078b9726
a=ice-ufrag:d238b152
a=mid:0
a=msid:{23cd2d5f-bba0-44c1-864c-a2e45ef7dea9} {72b45279-8868-4950-a352-62f19035b630}
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000/1
a=setup:passive
a=ssrc:3915669289 cname:{0cc435ca-987f-4679-abe7-e250eb82ec3a}
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 98
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=sendrecv
a=fmtp:96 max-fs=12288;max-fr=60
a=fmtp:98 max-fs=12288;max-fr=60
a=ice-pwd:ad33262c89431a763c05ff11078b9726
a=ice-ufrag:d238b152
a=mid:1
a=msid:{23cd2d5f-bba0-44c1-864c-a2e45ef7dea9} {91e5cfec-72bd-4df9-a367-c17769f8be97}
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000
a=setup:passive
a=ssrc:2924201237 cname:{0cc435ca-987f-4679-abe7-e250eb82ec3a}
m=application 9 DTLS/SCTP 5000
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=sendrecv
a=ice-pwd:ad33262c89431a763c05ff11078b9726
a=ice-ufrag:d238b152
a=mid:2
a=sctpmap:5000 webrtc-datachannel 256
a=setup:passive
a=max-message-size:1073741823

Peer A can see/ear peer B.

Disabling the broadcasting results as follows:
Remote SDP (offer from SFU)
v=0
o=- 5646507004176508049 1713867601 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
s=-
t=0 0
a=fingerprint:sha-256 47:6A:71:15:C0:01:A4:3E:B6:AC:C6:8B:E2:84:B1:C0:1D:49:6F:F1:14:0C:1F:C4:BD:B2:30:56:10:BB:9D:36
a=group:BUNDLE 0 1 2
m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 0 8 9
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:0
a=ice-ufrag:WRtsEOiaoItPEqup
a=ice-pwd:eadmhjMMzpurJPeaIqdGCwUyihOpRLzv
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=recvonly
a=candidate:foundation 1 udp 2130706431 192.168.1.3 34668 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 2 udp 2130706431 192.168.1.3 34668 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 1 udp 2130706431 192.168.122.1 53777 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 2 udp 2130706431 192.168.122.1 53777 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 1 udp 2130706431 172.17.0.1 49086 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 2 udp 2130706431 172.17.0.1 49086 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 1 udp 16777215 2.32.201.189 51726 typ relay raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 54578 generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 2 udp 16777215 2.32.201.189 51726 typ relay raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 54578 generation 0
a=end-of-candidates
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 98 102
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:1
a=ice-ufrag:WRtsEOiaoItPEqup
a=ice-pwd:eadmhjMMzpurJPeaIqdGCwUyihOpRLzv
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000
a=rtpmap:102 H264/90000
a=fmtp:102 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42001f
a=recvonly
a=candidate:foundation 1 udp 2130706431 192.168.1.3 34668 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 2 udp 2130706431 192.168.1.3 34668 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 1 udp 2130706431 192.168.122.1 53777 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 2 udp 2130706431 192.168.122.1 53777 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 1 udp 2130706431 172.17.0.1 49086 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 2 udp 2130706431 172.17.0.1 49086 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 1 udp 16777215 2.32.201.189 51726 typ relay raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 54578 generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 2 udp 16777215 2.32.201.189 51726 typ relay raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 54578 generation 0
a=end-of-candidates
m=application 9 DTLS/SCTP 5000
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:2
a=sendrecv
a=sctpmap:5000 webrtc-datachannel 1024
a=ice-ufrag:WRtsEOiaoItPEqup
a=ice-pwd:eadmhjMMzpurJPeaIqdGCwUyihOpRLzv
a=candidate:foundation 1 udp 2130706431 192.168.1.3 34668 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 2 udp 2130706431 192.168.1.3 34668 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 1 udp 2130706431 192.168.122.1 53777 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 2 udp 2130706431 192.168.122.1 53777 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 1 udp 2130706431 172.17.0.1 49086 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 2 udp 2130706431 172.17.0.1 49086 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 1 udp 16777215 2.32.201.189 51726 typ relay raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 54578 generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 2 udp 16777215 2.32.201.189 51726 typ relay raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 54578 generation 0
a=end-of-candidates

Local SDP (answer from Firefox)
v=0
o=mozilla...THIS_IS_SDPARTA-99.0 957846499555280282 3 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
s=-
t=0 0
a=fingerprint:sha-256 F1:90:80:57:6B:21:4B:3B:46:39:BE:EC:DD:DA:8B:EB:0B:41:CA:39:42:87:F6:71:CC:DD:E9:86:4D:3D:F4:00
a=group:BUNDLE 0 1 2
a=ice-options:trickle
a=msid-semantic:WMS *
m=audio 35036 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 0 8 9
c=IN IP4 2.32.201.189
a=candidate:0 1 UDP 2122252543 192.168.1.3 45832 typ host
a=candidate:3 1 UDP 2122187007 192.168.122.1 57330 typ host
a=candidate:6 1 UDP 2122121471 172.17.0.1 57309 typ host
a=candidate:9 1 TCP 2105524479 192.168.1.3 9 typ host tcptype active
a=candidate:11 1 TCP 2105458943 192.168.122.1 9 typ host tcptype active
a=candidate:13 1 TCP 2105393407 172.17.0.1 9 typ host tcptype active
a=candidate:10 1 UDP 8331263 2.32.201.189 35036 typ relay raddr 2.32.201.189 rport 35036
a=candidate:12 1 UDP 8265727 2.32.201.189 50962 typ relay raddr 2.32.201.189 rport 50962
a=candidate:14 1 UDP 8200191 2.32.201.189 50650 typ relay raddr 2.32.201.189 rport 50650
a=sendonly
a=end-of-candidates
a=fmtp:111 maxplaybackrate=48000;stereo=1;useinbandfec=1
a=ice-pwd:ad33262c89431a763c05ff11078b9726
a=ice-ufrag:d238b152
a=mid:0
a=msid:{23cd2d5f-bba0-44c1-864c-a2e45ef7dea9} {72b45279-8868-4950-a352-62f19035b630}
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000/1
a=setup:passive
a=ssrc:3915669289 cname:{0cc435ca-987f-4679-abe7-e250eb82ec3a}
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 98
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=sendonly
a=fmtp:96 max-fs=12288;max-fr=60
a=fmtp:98 max-fs=12288;max-fr=60
a=ice-pwd:ad33262c89431a763c05ff11078b9726
a=ice-ufrag:d238b152
a=mid:1
a=msid:{23cd2d5f-bba0-44c1-864c-a2e45ef7dea9} {91e5cfec-72bd-4df9-a367-c17769f8be97}
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000
a=setup:passive
a=ssrc:2924201237 cname:{0cc435ca-987f-4679-abe7-e250eb82ec3a}
m=application 9 DTLS/SCTP 5000
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=sendrecv
a=ice-pwd:ad33262c89431a763c05ff11078b9726
a=ice-ufrag:d238b152
a=mid:2
a=sctpmap:5000 webrtc-datachannel 256
a=setup:passive
a=max-message-size:1073741823


Reenabling the broadcasting results as follows:
Remote SDP (offer from SFU)
v=0
o=- 8896423429130464586 1713867815 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
s=-
t=0 0
a=fingerprint:sha-256 47:6A:71:15:C0:01:A4:3E:B6:AC:C6:8B:E2:84:B1:C0:1D:49:6F:F1:14:0C:1F:C4:BD:B2:30:56:10:BB:9D:36
a=group:BUNDLE 0 1 2 3 4
m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 0 8 9
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:0
a=ice-ufrag:WRtsEOiaoItPEqup
a=ice-pwd:eadmhjMMzpurJPeaIqdGCwUyihOpRLzv
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=recvonly
a=candidate:foundation 1 udp 2130706431 192.168.1.3 34668 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 2 udp 2130706431 192.168.1.3 34668 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 1 udp 2130706431 192.168.122.1 53777 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 2 udp 2130706431 192.168.122.1 53777 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 1 udp 2130706431 172.17.0.1 49086 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 2 udp 2130706431 172.17.0.1 49086 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 1 udp 16777215 2.32.201.189 51726 typ relay raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 54578 generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 2 udp 16777215 2.32.201.189 51726 typ relay raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 54578 generation 0
a=end-of-candidates
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 98 102
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:1
a=ice-ufrag:WRtsEOiaoItPEqup
a=ice-pwd:eadmhjMMzpurJPeaIqdGCwUyihOpRLzv
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000
a=rtpmap:102 H264/90000
a=fmtp:102 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42001f
a=recvonly
a=candidate:foundation 1 udp 2130706431 192.168.1.3 34668 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 2 udp 2130706431 192.168.1.3 34668 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 1 udp 2130706431 192.168.122.1 53777 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 2 udp 2130706431 192.168.122.1 53777 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 1 udp 2130706431 172.17.0.1 49086 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 2 udp 2130706431 172.17.0.1 49086 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 1 udp 16777215 2.32.201.189 51726 typ relay raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 54578 generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 2 udp 16777215 2.32.201.189 51726 typ relay raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 54578 generation 0
a=end-of-candidates
m=application 9 DTLS/SCTP 5000
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:2
a=sendrecv
a=sctpmap:5000 webrtc-datachannel 1024
a=ice-ufrag:WRtsEOiaoItPEqup
a=ice-pwd:eadmhjMMzpurJPeaIqdGCwUyihOpRLzv
a=candidate:foundation 1 udp 2130706431 192.168.1.3 34668 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 2 udp 2130706431 192.168.1.3 34668 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 1 udp 2130706431 192.168.122.1 53777 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 2 udp 2130706431 192.168.122.1 53777 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 1 udp 2130706431 172.17.0.1 49086 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 2 udp 2130706431 172.17.0.1 49086 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 1 udp 16777215 2.32.201.189 51726 typ relay raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 54578 generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 2 udp 16777215 2.32.201.189 51726 typ relay raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 54578 generation 0
a=end-of-candidates
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 98 102
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:3
a=ice-ufrag:WRtsEOiaoItPEqup
a=ice-pwd:eadmhjMMzpurJPeaIqdGCwUyihOpRLzv
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000
a=rtpmap:102 H264/90000
a=fmtp:102 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42001f
a=ssrc:2184094840 cname:{ccedd829-80b6-4d6e-95d5-5ea497e9a4fd}
a=ssrc:2184094840 msid:{ccedd829-80b6-4d6e-95d5-5ea497e9a4fd} ed97af1a-2ed6-4f13-9ca5-a989ded52e33
a=ssrc:2184094840 mslabel:{ccedd829-80b6-4d6e-95d5-5ea497e9a4fd}
a=ssrc:2184094840 label:ed97af1a-2ed6-4f13-9ca5-a989ded52e33
a=msid:{ccedd829-80b6-4d6e-95d5-5ea497e9a4fd} ed97af1a-2ed6-4f13-9ca5-a989ded52e33
a=sendrecv
a=candidate:foundation 1 udp 2130706431 192.168.1.3 34668 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 2 udp 2130706431 192.168.1.3 34668 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 1 udp 2130706431 192.168.122.1 53777 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 2 udp 2130706431 192.168.122.1 53777 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 1 udp 2130706431 172.17.0.1 49086 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 2 udp 2130706431 172.17.0.1 49086 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 1 udp 16777215 2.32.201.189 51726 typ relay raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 54578 generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 2 udp 16777215 2.32.201.189 51726 typ relay raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 54578 generation 0
a=end-of-candidates
m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 0 8 9
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:4
a=ice-ufrag:WRtsEOiaoItPEqup
a=ice-pwd:eadmhjMMzpurJPeaIqdGCwUyihOpRLzv
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=ssrc:556646705 cname:{ccedd829-80b6-4d6e-95d5-5ea497e9a4fd}
a=ssrc:556646705 msid:{ccedd829-80b6-4d6e-95d5-5ea497e9a4fd} 6e65e23b-ca79-49c9-8fa2-db07bcf7d813
a=ssrc:556646705 mslabel:{ccedd829-80b6-4d6e-95d5-5ea497e9a4fd}
a=ssrc:556646705 label:6e65e23b-ca79-49c9-8fa2-db07bcf7d813
a=msid:{ccedd829-80b6-4d6e-95d5-5ea497e9a4fd} 6e65e23b-ca79-49c9-8fa2-db07bcf7d813
a=sendrecv
a=candidate:foundation 1 udp 2130706431 192.168.1.3 34668 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 2 udp 2130706431 192.168.1.3 34668 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 1 udp 2130706431 192.168.122.1 53777 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 2 udp 2130706431 192.168.122.1 53777 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 1 udp 2130706431 172.17.0.1 49086 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 2 udp 2130706431 172.17.0.1 49086 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 1 udp 16777215 2.32.201.189 51726 typ relay raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 54578 generation 0
a=candidate:foundation 2 udp 16777215 2.32.201.189 51726 typ relay raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 54578 generation 0
a=end-of-candidates

Local SDP (answer from Firefox)
v=0
o=mozilla...THIS_IS_SDPARTA-99.0 957846499555280282 4 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
s=-
t=0 0
a=fingerprint:sha-256 F1:90:80:57:6B:21:4B:3B:46:39:BE:EC:DD:DA:8B:EB:0B:41:CA:39:42:87:F6:71:CC:DD:E9:86:4D:3D:F4:00
a=group:BUNDLE 0 1 2 3 4
a=ice-options:trickle
a=msid-semantic:WMS *
m=audio 35036 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 0 8 9
c=IN IP4 2.32.201.189
a=candidate:0 1 UDP 2122252543 192.168.1.3 45832 typ host
a=candidate:3 1 UDP 2122187007 192.168.122.1 57330 typ host
a=candidate:6 1 UDP 2122121471 172.17.0.1 57309 typ host
a=candidate:9 1 TCP 2105524479 192.168.1.3 9 typ host tcptype active
a=candidate:11 1 TCP 2105458943 192.168.122.1 9 typ host tcptype active
a=candidate:13 1 TCP 2105393407 172.17.0.1 9 typ host tcptype active
a=candidate:10 1 UDP 8331263 2.32.201.189 35036 typ relay raddr 2.32.201.189 rport 35036
a=candidate:12 1 UDP 8265727 2.32.201.189 50962 typ relay raddr 2.32.201.189 rport 50962
a=candidate:14 1 UDP 8200191 2.32.201.189 50650 typ relay raddr 2.32.201.189 rport 50650
a=sendonly
a=end-of-candidates
a=fmtp:111 maxplaybackrate=48000;stereo=1;useinbandfec=1
a=ice-pwd:ad33262c89431a763c05ff11078b9726
a=ice-ufrag:d238b152
a=mid:0
a=msid:{23cd2d5f-bba0-44c1-864c-a2e45ef7dea9} {72b45279-8868-4950-a352-62f19035b630}
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000/1
a=setup:passive
a=ssrc:3915669289 cname:{0cc435ca-987f-4679-abe7-e250eb82ec3a}
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 98
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=sendonly
a=fmtp:96 max-fs=12288;max-fr=60
a=fmtp:98 max-fs=12288;max-fr=60
a=ice-pwd:ad33262c89431a763c05ff11078b9726
a=ice-ufrag:d238b152
a=mid:1
a=msid:{23cd2d5f-bba0-44c1-864c-a2e45ef7dea9} {91e5cfec-72bd-4df9-a367-c17769f8be97}
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000
a=setup:passive
a=ssrc:2924201237 cname:{0cc435ca-987f-4679-abe7-e250eb82ec3a}
m=application 9 DTLS/SCTP 5000
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=sendrecv
a=ice-pwd:ad33262c89431a763c05ff11078b9726
a=ice-ufrag:d238b152
a=mid:2
a=sctpmap:5000 webrtc-datachannel 256
a=setup:passive
a=max-message-size:1073741823
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 98
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=recvonly
a=fmtp:96 max-fs=12288;max-fr=60
a=fmtp:98 max-fs=12288;max-fr=60
a=ice-pwd:ad33262c89431a763c05ff11078b9726
a=ice-ufrag:d238b152
a=mid:3
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000
a=setup:active
a=ssrc:1868673906 cname:{0cc435ca-987f-4679-abe7-e250eb82ec3a}
m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 0 8 9
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=recvonly
a=fmtp:111 maxplaybackrate=48000;stereo=1;useinbandfec=1
a=ice-pwd:ad33262c89431a763c05ff11078b9726
a=ice-ufrag:d238b152
a=mid:4
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000/1
a=setup:active
a=ssrc:2201530307 cname:{0cc435ca-987f-4679-abe7-e250eb82ec3a}

Peer A cannot see/ear again the peer B.

What does firefox://webrtc-internals reveal?

@BGPHiJACK I completely forgot about webrtc internals. I updated the question (first section, behaviors lists).

You're describing more to me a problem that deals with your client and server code. I don't use that SFU but could suggest you debug and monitor to ensure your requests aren't being completed out of order and causing these hiccups.

I'd start by ensuring the transport opened in the SFU contains both tracks audio/video, should be able to narrow in if this is a communication between client and server problem, a client sided bug or w/e.

@BGPHiJACK, there could certainly be bugs on the SFU/javascript side, but the fact that it can be reproduced exactly once every other time, and that it always works on Chrome, makes me rule out timing and transport problems, which is why I included the SDPs, thinking it was something low level, specific to Firefox.

Even the fact that by keeping the video muted the broadcast toggle works correctly even on Firefox is something unusual, because the audio/video tracks are always there in the exchanged SDPs.

That feels like it might also be an HDMI audio driver issue. I've seen more than one machine refuse to play video (streamed or from file) when audio is enabled, only to magically play video just fine the instant audio gets muted. How many machines are you testing with?
